# Spring with OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I'm doing some tests with Spring + OAuth2 authentication and when I try to get a token, I'm always asked for password. My application is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
                throws Exception {
            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager auth;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        @Bean
        public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
                throws Exception {
            security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                    .authenticationManager(auth).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .approvalStoreDisabled();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.jdbc(dataSource)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                            "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_USER").scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource").secret("secret");
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withUser("dave")
                    .password("secret").roles("USER", "ACTUATOR");
            // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

I'm doing the tests with Restlet chrome plugin:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're probably missing the authorization header, it should be `Basic base64(cient_id:client_secret)`.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was it. now how I use the token?

Comment: Same way. you have to specify the `Authorization` token in the web service request, `TokenType token_value` for example `bearer sdfadsfaserwer23432`